Show line-breaks automatically for long texts in LibreOffice Calc
How do I make LibreOffice Calc line-break long text automatically without inserting actual line-breaks into the text?
I have a spreadsheet with a column with long text that regularly stretch across the screen. This make editing awkward. I would like to have the text automatically line-broken for easier overview.
Note, there are multiple questions about adding line-breaks in cells, but I want the text intact, just shown across multiple lines.
Also note: One could achieve this by manually stretching the columns across multiple lines, but that is not feasible for the amount of entries I have.
What it looks like:

What it should look like (HTML mock):

In Notepad++ this is achieved by selecting View => Word wrap, but I have failed to locate a similar functionality in LibreOffice Calc.


Select all the cells where you want the text to break at the right border.
In Format - Cells - Alignment, mark the Wrap text automatically option and click OK.

text wrap, LibreOfffice documentation

One way to get an overview of the values, if one is OK with editing 1 cell at the time, is to click the Expand Formula Bar button.

This opens a multi-line editor for the selected cell value. It doesn't give the overview of every cell value, as requested in the question, though.
